# Как сделать роли в базе данных с ENUM

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Хочу реализовать, чтобы у пользователей были роли. Есть 2 Entity: user и role. В базе данных прописаны стандартные атрибуты. Для User: id,name,surname,phone,role,email. Для role:id,name. Где и как прописать мне через ENUM 3 роли: "ADMIN, LANDLORD, TENANT". Мы создадим новый класс ROLES, (либо вообще можно не создавать, наверное, а просто перечислим в классе), где будет хранить эти три роли. А как нам их соединить с USER и ROLE?

Пример POST запроса, который буду делать для добавления пользователя:
Вася, Петренко,910382741, vasya@mail.ru, ADMIN
Первые 4 атрибута работают, а вот как сделать поле для роли - не понимаю.

USER

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "task")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    // Связали роли OneToMany к Роли, здесь точно нужно использовать список?
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private List<Role> role;

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer phone;
}
```

ROLE

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "role", schema = "task")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

}
```

Класс с ролями

```
public enum Roles {
    TENANT,LANDLORD,ADMIN
}
```

Comment: Соединить что? И где попытки кодировать?

Comment: Если пользователь будет иметь только одну роль, то нет смысла создавать доп entity под нее. Поместите роль в таблицу юзера.

Comment: @AlekseiGaile пользователь может иметь несколько ролей

Comment: @Roman я пытаюсь сделать, чтобы перечисление ролей было сделано с помощью ENUM. У меня просто даже идей никаких нет, как это можно сделать. Смог только всё подготовить, а дальше не знаю. Допустим, я хочу, чтобы через postman делал запрос вот так во время добавления пользователя: Вася, Петренко,910382741, vasya@mail.ru, ADMIN

Comment: @AlekseiGaile а что под собой подразумевает помещение роли в таблицу юзера?

Comment: @Blacit создать колонку Roles в Entity User

Comment: @Blacit Но раз нужно несколько ролей, то этот вариант не подходит. Соответственно две таблицы со связью один ко многим и вместо String name в таблице роль, надо поставить Roles role

Comment: @AlekseiGaile Хорошо, можете подсказать, что дальше нужно сделать?

Comment: @Blacit не совсем понимаю вопрос. На беке - создаете объект Role role, setRole(Roles.Admin), создаете пользователя, где заполняете его поля и задаете user.setRole(role). Заполнять роли с фронта наверно не совсем хороший вариант, можно в пропертях предусмотреть Админа, а остальные роли раздавать в нужных контроллерах. Все зависит от реализации.

Comment: Можете подсказать почему необходимо в таблице роль поставить Role role вместо name? Как этот атрибут тогда обозначить в базе данных. У меня это задание как обучающее, так что админа можно и из запроса делать, чтобы понять как в целом всё строить. Дальше подкручу секьюрити, чтобы роли раздавать. Пока что нужно понять как в целом реализовать, чтобы роли можно было присваивать пользователям. Мне советовали как в ENUM использовать, чтобы всё было компактно.

Comment: @AlekseiGaile Смотрите, как нам проверить, есть ли в БД такие роли, как админ, арендатор или собственник? У меня вариант - это енум, но не совсем понимаю как в контроллере прописать проверку по енуму. Можете это продемонстрировать, пожалуйста? Логика запроса проста: Вася, Петренко,910382741, vasya@mail.ru, ADMIN Вот нам нужно проверить, чтобы пользователь правильно написал ADMIN и в целом наличие этой роли

Comment: @Blacit, пользователь не должен назначать свою роль, ее выдаете вы, как разработчик или Админ, это  в идеале. Если уж вы решили что пользователь должен так писать - сделайте select на фронте, где роли прописаны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо сделать тип `enum` с текстовыми значениями:

```
public enum Roles {
    TENANT ("tenant"),
    LANDLORD ("landlord"),
    ADMIN ("admin");

    private final String name;       

    private Roles(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public boolean equalsName(String otherName) {
        return name.equals(otherName);
    }

    public String toString() {
       return this.name;
    }
}
```

Дальше уже дело техники писать в БД их текстовые значения, а при извлечении из БД маппировать на `enum Roles`

Comment: Я немного доделал вот так получлось: `public enum Roles {
    TENANT ("tenant"),
    LANDLORD ("landlord"),
    ADMIN ("admin");

    private String name;

    private void Modes(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    Roles(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean equalsName(String otherName) {
        return name.equals(otherName);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}` Потому что всё красным горело. Я же верно понимаю, что потом нам нужно как-то это связать с классом Role (этот класс у меня в топике есть)

Comment: Я исправил ошибки копипейста :) `Modes` на `Roles`